# Are there any code complexity metering tools that work well with ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs, code-complexity, plato

My project is ES6 (webpack + babel). [Plato](https://github.com/es-analysis/plato) is great, but doesn't work with ES6 [yet](https://github.com/es-analysis/plato/issues/127). I took a look at [escomplex](https://github.com/philbooth/escomplex) and the series of related packages, but it looks like the author is no longer maintaining this and it seems like it doesn't support ES6 anyways.

I'm using the [ESLint complexity rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/complexity.html) to at least warn me if there's an issue (it's set to warn at 6), but it's not the same as a pretty report.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [**fork**](https://github.com/deedubs/es6-plato) created by [deedubs](https://github.com/deedubs) that **uses** [**espree**](https://github.com/eslint/espree) **instead** [**esprima**](http://esprima.org/). I've installed it and it runs on ES6 styled code like a charm, in order to install the fork version instead the default distro execute the following command:

```
npm install -g git+https://github.com/deedubs/es6-plato.git
```

Whenever you want to uninstall it just do it like you would do it with vanilla plato install by writing

`npm uninstall plato`

Here's a screenshot for a file report based on a ES6 code after installing the Plato forked version

[image]

It's been about 3 weeks since you asked the question so I am not sure if this will be still useful for you but I hope it can help others with the same problem we were facing on using this amazing tool.

Comment: But doesn't Esprima parse ES6 just as well?

Comment: You are right I missed some part of the explanation for the sake of simplicity, the long story is a little more complicated since he made the **replace** in a Plato **dependency** tree, the top level library it depends is named  **escomplex-js** that is wrapper over a non longer maintained library named *escomplex* original version was relaying in an **old esprima version**, some other guy already made half of the job but forgot to enable all es6 options for espree **deedubs** fixed all the es6 problems on this fork as far as I understand, it's been working for me so far so go.

Answer (score 3):

I published a version of plato that does this here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-plato

- updates lodash and dependencies
- fixes some common bugs in plato
- properly parses es6
- this includes classes

`npm install --save es6-plato`

read the docs to use it with gulp, or via the js api.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That looks awesome, I'll check it out.

For anyone following this, we ended up going with [SonarQube](https://sonarqube.com/).

Comment: @sak_to Would you accept this answer? This is a maintained fork of the answer you accepted, which seems to be not maintained anymore.